# 2 Quartz jobs updating same value in db concurrently causing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, race-condition

I had one quartz job doing some stuff and taking lot of time for one particular case and others are very quick. So I don't want to stop my job waiting when one slow case is running for very long time and other things are complete.  This job runs and checks doStuff flag. when doStuff==1 run do things and make value to 0. So that when next time job is triggered it should not run already done stuff.

So to solve above problem I created 2 jobs. A- quick performing job, B-slow moving job.

I have 2 quartz jobs A & B running concurrently and using one flag to decide whether to run job & do stuff or to run and exit without doing any stuff.
I have a flag doStuff and it has initial value as 0 . when it's value is 1 then both job should start doing stuff and when they finish they should update value back to 0. When value is 0 and job started then this job won't do it'a stuff.
The work both job A & B doing is exactly same but different parameters.
Ideally both job should run when flag is 1 and do stuff and update value to 0.
But when first job runs and completes before starting second job, it is updating value to 0 and  when second runs it reads value 0 and won't do any stuff.

The doStuff flag is DB column. I can add one more column for job B, but that's not a good design as we may get requirement of job C, job D and I can't add column for each requirement.

Is there any better way to handle this problem?

Note: I am new to Quartz framework.

Tried using new column for flag but not a good design. Tried locking but that also won't solve problem .

Below is how execute method of InterruptableJob looks like

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobContext.getMergedJobDataMap();
    final long customerId = jobDataMap.getLong(CUSTOMER_ID_KEY);

    List < QAgentAssetSourceInfo > customerAgents = getValuesBasedOnDoStuff();

    // below code is in Runnable run method and will be started in new thread 
    {
        failedAgents.putAll(agentMgmtHelper.get().doStuff(customerAgents, customer.getId(), null, batchSize));


        // we are done with stuff now make value to 0
        unsetDoStuff();
    });

}
```

Comment: Add a column such as _JOB_NAME_ so there can be a row per job, instead of column per job.  Then do something like `unsetDoStuff([get job name from context])` which sets the _DOSTUFF_ column for the particular row associated with the job name.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but there can be millions of rows and we are doing stuff on those rows. If we add one more row for each record then it will double the records.

Comment: You create a flag-column with n positions (one for every job (A,B, ..)). To `doStuff` you set the column to 111...  and every job checks it's flag position and sets to 0 when done. When you get more jobs, simply increase the column.

Comment: Thanks Sascha.What if both job picks up value as 11 and then one updates as 10 and second updates as 01 . So next time job will either read 10 or 01 depends on which thread finishes first. Ideally next time job should read value as 00.